# Encapsulation of logic and interface on iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I assume this is going to be a very basic question, but maybe somebody can help me. I've come to iPhone SDK from a C# .NET background.

I would like to know if there is some mechanism similar to what is called in ASP.NET "UserControl" which encapsulates logic and interface. It would be desirable to launch "events" too.

I'm trying to design something like a common header for the entire application, which shows different types of buttons depending of the view where it is placed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all thanks for your contribution. I realized that I was looking for something different: The views (yeah, I know there were here since the beginning).

I've realized that **when I allocate one of my controllers by default it tries to load the xib with the same name**. Therefore, I can design the view on the interface builder and then load it on another view as a subview (that's similar to usercontrol concept).

How to make the view adjust to the desired size?:

```
Controller *controller = [[Controller alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 200);
[self.view addSubview:controller.view];
```

The only missing here is how to comunicate the view with the subview, but I supose that can be made with a reference to the parent.

Thanks a lot

(PS: I'm going to check the answer as correct just for close the thread. I don't know if this procedure is the best or has enough quality)

Answer (score 1):

Normally Objective C will support only single Inheritance.We can achieve multiple inheritance
through Delegates  called as protocols(user defined).i think it will help you when you google based on this(user defined protocols in iphone sdk).